# How to call API in solidity with ethereum private network

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, chainlink

I'm trying to call external API in smart contract code with Ethereum private network but didn't get any solution.

I have also gone through chainlink solutions but I didn't get oracle id and job id from **markt.link** as per latest website update.

Can someone please help me out on how to make HTTP get/post requests in solidity with Ethereum private network?

Comment: I would not recommend making API requests in solidity.  These should be done on the application side of things if anything.

Comment: You will need to spin up Chainlink Node(s) in local as well.

Comment: @Andrej, can you please share any link or suggestion on how to spin up Chainlink Node(s) in local?

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution, pretty much the same thing as for public networks, just need to point to your private network

Comment: @Andrej, can you please give some reference link ?

Answer (score 1):

Solidity is compiled to EVM (Ethereum Virtual Machine) bytecode. To keep all operations deterministic, the code running inside the VM cannot communicate with resources outside of the VM.

Having said that, there are services such as Chainlink, allowing you to communicate with external APIs from Solidity code on public networks. When you invoke a specific Chainlink SDK function passing it an API URL and other params, it emits Solidity event. Their offchain app is listening to this event, queries the URL and sends back a new transaction to your contract, containing the result.

There are no Chainlink nodes on your private network. So on a private network, you can replicate this approach with your own offchain application.

*Solidity:*

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    event DataRequested(string url);

    function requestData(string memory url) public {
        emit DataRequested(url);
    }

    function receiveData(bytes memory data) public {
        // it's recommended to validate `msg.sender`
        // and allow for this function to be invoked only from an authorized address
        require(msg.sender == address(0x123));
    }
}
```

*JS:*

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const web3 = new Web3(YOUR_NODE_URL);

const myContract = new web3.eth.Contract(ABI, ADDRESS);

// handle the event when it's emitted
myContract.events.DataRequested(async (eventData) => {
    // process the URL
    const result = queryUrl(eventData.returnValues.url);

    // send the data back from the authorized address
    // your local `web3` instance or the node need to know the private key of `0x123` address
    await myContract.methods.receiveData(result).send({
        from: "0x123"
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank You soo much for your quick reply!

I'll definitely apply your logic and check if it works or not.

Comment: I applied your solidity logic in remix but I'm not be able to get the result data

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution Remix IDE by default uses an emulator network (Javascript VM) that is not available outside of the browser. If you want to connect your offchain app and a smart contract, you'll need to use either an emulator able to share data between local apps (such as Ganache or Truffle) or a private network that you mentioned in your question.

Comment: Remix also provides injected web3 functionality through which we can connect our private network  and deploy

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution That's correct. Based on your previous comment, I assumed you're using the integrated emulator. If you cannot use the example on a correct network, please provide more info to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I just want to make an API call in solidity with private network. If it works in remix then I can easily access property solidity using web3.

Comment: @TrimantraSoftwareSolution Accessing Solidity property from an offchain app is not usually described as API call. However you can use the web3js function [myContract.methods.myMethod.call()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.7.3/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call) from an offchain app, after you have connected to a node of the private network that has the JSON-RPC API enabled.

Comment: Yes, In that way I can call the function but in your call how it will call an API and return value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245777/discussion-between-trimantra-software-solution-and-petr-hejda).